# Why does this code print out "0"

Tags: java

I've run into a problem with my code. I know the answer is 9 but my code prints out 0 and i'm not sure why. I have 2 classes to make it run. A method class and a Tester class to see if it works. Can anyone spot out my error?

```
public class Robot
{
private int[] hall;
private int pos;
private boolean facingRight;

private boolean forwardMoveBlocked()
{
    if (facingRight) 
    {
        return pos == hall.length - 1;
    }
    else
    {
    return pos == 0;
    }
}

private void move()
{
    if (hall[pos] > 0)
    {
        hall[pos]--;
    }

    if (hall[pos] == 0
    {
        if (forwardMoveBlocked())
        {
            facingRight = !facingRight;
        }
        else
        {
            if (facingRight) 
            {
                pos++;
            }
            else
            {
                pos--;
            }
        }
    }
}

public int clearHall()
{
    int count = 0;
    while (!hallIsClear())
    {
        move();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public boolen hallIsClear()
{   
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is my tester class code

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Robot RobotTest = new Robot();
        System.out.println( RobotTest.clearHall() );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis here: `if (hall[pos] == 0`

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Did you try this in the debugger? It would have shown you the problem right away.

Comment: `move()` is never called, take another look at your logic.

Comment: boolen doesn't exist, use boolean instead.

Comment: You never initialize hall[pos]...

Comment: Yeah that was my bad about that parenthesis and typing boolen instead of boolean. My copy didnt seem to overwrite my previous copy and i pasted the previous version

Comment: @EmbattledSwag I *believe* that with an appropriate IDE (or even the messages from javac on the command line), that isn't an issue *yet* - there's lots of dead code there, and the initialization checks don't care about dead code.  Once the loop is fixed to run, that will indeed be an issue (it may not compile).

Answer (score 11):

Your `while` loop calls NOT `hallIsClear()`, which in turn always returns `true`.

Therefore, no call to `move()` nor any increment of `count` is made.

The value of `count` stays at `0` and is returned as such.

By the way your code will not compile, as `hallIsClear()` returns `boolen` instead of `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

Because hallIsClear returns always true.

When you call

```
 while (!hallIsClear())
    {
        move();
        count++;
    }
```

the loop will never run, because hallIsClear always returns true. 
On the other hand, if you will change it to

> while (hallIsClear())

there will be an infinite loop. You have to follow a different design in you code.

Comment: i called for the method clearHall() not hallIsClear